# Heapsize in javacore and heapdump: 20x difference on IBM JVM

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, websphere, heap-memory

It was noticed that the production server (Websphere8.5.5) started to consume an enormous amount of memory.

The figures in javacore dump clearly tell that the culprit is an outgrown heap:

```
|  +--Memory Manager (GC): 5,496,900,272 bytes / 3193 allocations
|  |  |
|  |  +--Java Heap: 5,368,770,560 bytes / 1 allocation
|  |  |
|  |  +--Other: 128,129,712 bytes / 3192 allocations
```

But at the same time, heap dump opened in MAT reports the total volume of the heap as about 200M (sometimes up to 300M, but never more).

What does it really mean? Is the heap dump trustworthy? If yes, is there a way to free up unused heap memory?

UPDATE: the complete NATIVEMEM section, as requested

```
1MEMUSER       JRE: 7,211,791,256 bytes / 39196 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--VM: 6,772,051,048 bytes / 29934 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Classes: 370,339,176 bytes / 10002 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Shared Class Cache: 62,914,560 bytes / 1 allocation
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 307,424,616 bytes / 10001 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Memory Manager (GC): 5,496,900,272 bytes / 3193 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Heap: 5,368,770,560 bytes / 1 allocation
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 128,129,712 bytes / 3192 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Threads: 91,710,312 bytes / 3408 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Java Stack: 5,958,456 bytes / 349 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Native Stack: 68,812,800 bytes / 248 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 16,939,056 bytes / 2811 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Trace: 3,415,376 bytes / 1229 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JVMTI: 17,776 bytes / 13 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JNI: 5,821,768 bytes / 9844 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Port Library: 794,750,560 bytes / 401 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Unused <32bit allocation regions: 794,704,552 bytes / 87 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 46,008 bytes / 314 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 9,095,808 bytes / 1844 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--JIT: 436,874,280 bytes / 8850 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Code Cache: 268,435,456 bytes / 1 allocation
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--JIT Data Cache: 48,235,968 bytes / 23 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Other: 120,202,856 bytes / 8826 allocations
1MEMUSER       |
2MEMUSER       +--Class Libraries: 2,865,928 bytes / 412 allocations
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--Harmony Class Libraries: 2,000 bytes / 1 allocation
2MEMUSER       |  |
3MEMUSER       |  +--VM Class Libraries: 2,863,928 bytes / 411 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--sun.misc.Unsafe: 2,635,720 bytes / 307 allocations
4MEMUSER       |  |  |  |
5MEMUSER       |  |  |  +--Direct Byte Buffers: 2,625,112 bytes / 304 allocations
4MEMUSER       |  |  |  |
5MEMUSER       |  |  |  +--Other: 10,608 bytes / 3 allocations
3MEMUSER       |  |  |
4MEMUSER       |  |  +--Other: 228,208 bytes / 104 allocations
```

Comment: The only strange thing I see is that there are ~750MB of freed 32-bit allocation regions. That might suggest unneeded churn of some kind. But I would first start by gathering the matching OS data on RSS/VSZ over time and periodic javacores. If RSS is going over -Xmx, then I'd be worried. You can open a support case if you need additional help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NATIVEMEMINFO` section shows virtual memory, so `5,368,770,560` simply means that the JVM has virtually allocated that much memory for the heap. How much is actually resident will depend on actual heap size and heap usage. If, for example, a lot of garbage builds up in the tenured region and then gets cleaned up in a full GC, then it could be that at some point those pages became resident, but how much is actually live depends on many factors. I believe when the JVM starts, it virtually allocates the full size of `-Xmx` so I think you'll always see the full size of the heap in NATIVEMEMINFO (it could also be that it only allocates `-Xms`, so if what you're seeing is larger than `-Xms`, then it means pressure drove the heap to increase [although of course, note the normal [sawtooth](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Java.html#Java-Garbage_Collection-Generational_Garbage_Collectors-The_Sawtooth)]).

When you load a dump in MAT, it runs a full garbage collection and removes any unreachable objects from the main view by default. You can click on the "Unreachable Objects Histogram" link on the Overview page and scroll to the bottom to the sum of shallow heap totals line to see how much "trash" is in the heapdump. There's also an option in MAT preferences to "Keep unreachable objects" which would keep all of those objects in the main MAT views, but that's usually not very useful.

So the basic answer is that MAT only shows you live objects, so at the time of your dumps, there was 200-300MB of live objects. The rest might either be in the trash, or simply never was there and NATIVEMEMINFO is just showing virtual size.

The better way to look at heap usage over time is verbosegc and load in [GCMV](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/httpserv/cookbook/Major_Tools-Garbage_Collection_and_Memory_Visualizer_GCMV.html):

```
-Xverbosegclog:verbosegc.%seq.log,20,50000
```

Comment: If we assume that JVM allocates the full Xmx at start, what is the role of Xms parameter in this case?

Comment: I just edited my answer as you were making this comment because I realized it could be the case it only virtually allocates `-Xms` and then would only increase the virtual allocations up to `-Xmx` if there's pressure (but that could be benign if it's just sawtooth growth of tenured; i.e. nurseries not keeping up with tenuring rate).

Comment: Thanks for the update. Finally, do you think there is a way to force jvm to free up part of the whole Xmx, when it is mostly unused? I mean native memory of course.

Comment: The JVM has the ability to do Java heap shrinkage but you'll be fighting an uphill battle to actually get the OS to free the memory because even if the JVM `free`s virtual memory, the standard C libraries (e.g. `libc` on Linux) will usually just put those allocations into their free lists rather than actually give the memory back to the OS. What is your goal?

Comment: BTW, checking "keep unreachable objects" in MAT added almost nothing to the displayed total volume of the heap dump.

Comment: You'll have to delete the `*index` files and re-parse the heapdump after checking that option, but don't bother - just click the "Unreachable objects histogram" link (without keep unreachables checked) and that will tell you how much is in the trash (go to the bottom totals line). The keep unreachables object is only if for some reason you need the relationships between the trash objects, which is very rare.

Comment: The goal is to make the memory available for the OS again. Because it happens quite often in our environment, that after some pike load is passed, the consumption could be barely above zero for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I removed *.index files before opening. But the result seems to be the same still...

Comment: If heap size is similar with and without keeping unreachable objects, then it means the dumps you have do not have much trash in them. You can cross-reference this with verbosegc.

Comment: BTW, I do not see "Unreachable objects histogram" in my MAT, which is v1.6.1. Do I have to upgrade?

Comment: If you're loading a PHD file, then there usually is no trash because the JVM runs a full garbage collection itself when requesting the PHD. I assumed you grabbed a core dump instead of a PHD since you're interested in native memory.

Comment: Anyway, back to the main question: why do you want to reduce resident memory? If you set `-Xmx` to some value, then, by definition, you expect that at any point, that much memory could become resident (and therefore, your RAM should be planned with `-Xmx` [plus a bit more because of native data structures] in mind).

Comment: I think you are right, and probably we should keep everything as is. It's just support guys are getting nervous when bunch of servers takes more and more memory and never gives it back. Just in case, if we want to try shrinking, what is the way to force it? Using -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio ?

Comment: You should think of `-Xmx` as a fixed allocation (although it might take some time for it to grow between `-Xms` and `-Xmx`); however, if you see the total resident memory of the JVM constantly increasing *above* `-Xmx`, then it could be that there's some leak outside of the Java heap (for example, classes/classloaders, threads, DirectByteBuffers, etc.). Can you please edit your question to show the entire `NATIVEMEMINFO` section and also the resident and virtual sizes reported by the OS of the PID?

Comment: Sorry for delaying, I added NATIVEMEM section to the question. I can't check by my own, but I was told by support guys, that memory volume reported by OS was very close to the total one of NATIVEMEM (about 7G).

Comment: BTW, I tried opening core dump with "keep unreachable objects" option, but it didn't change much. I'm just curious if it's possible to see those objects. Is there a way to prevent GC on dump request?

Comment: The most common causes of native memory issues are the native data structures behind classes, threads, JIT, and DirectByteBuffers. This shows ~400MB of classes, ~100MB of threads, ~500MB of JIT, and ~2MB of DirectByteBuffers. None of these seem to concerning (unless of course they're growing). I suggest periodically gathering javacores and OS virtual/resident stats (at the same time) and monitoring what exactly is growing (cross-reference the two).

Comment: As far as GCed objects, yes, you can disable the option of a GC on requesting PHD (or more simply just use a core dump instead which is a superset of PHD and usually doesn't GC on request), but my point was that this doesn't matter. It's perfectly normally for trash to be in the heap. From a native memory perspective, the size of the Java heap is a fixed size, so what's going on inside the heap doesn't matter. What you have to be concerned about is what's going on /outside/ the Java heap.